# Get XPath inner text without some but not all child

Tags: xpath, xhtml

I have some HTML like this

```
<div>
  <a>link that I do not want to get</a>
  <div>Div that I do not want to get</div>
  Text I want to get
  <br> I like brs
  <b>That text I also want, because I like bold text</b>
  <div>I do not want all divs</div>
</div>
```

And I'd like to use xpath to extract out just the

```
Text I want to get
<br> I like brs
<b>That text I also want, because I like bold text</b>
```

In other words I want all DIV childs, but not a and not div. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `self::a` to detect a elements, and then use `not` to exclude them, i.e.:

```
/div/node()[not(self::a or self::div)]
```